# Markov Chains on $\mathbb{C}^N$ are all the positive unital maps on $\mathbb{C}^N$

Tags: stochastic-processes, operator-theory, markov-chains, positive-matrices

Is there a biijection between all the markov chains represented by the stochastic matrices, and all the positive unital maps from $\Phi : \mathbb{C}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^N$?

I mean, given any unital positive map of this kind, will this be a stochastic matrix and therefore, a representation of a certain markov chain? And why is this true?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unital" in your setup is precisely "stochastic". Given one of your $\Phi$, you have $\Phi e=e$, where $e$ is the identity of $\mathbb C^N$. This equality, row by row, is 
$$
1=(\Phi e)_k=\sum_j\Phi_{kj}e_j=\sum_j\Phi_{kj}.
$$

Similarly, in this context $\Phi\geq0$, means that $\Phi x\geq0$ whenever $x\geq0$. It follows that $\Phi\geq0$ if and only if $\Phi_{kj}\geq0$ for all $k,j$. Indeed, suppose that $\Phi\geq0$. Thus
$$
0\leq \sum_k \Phi_{kj}a_j, \ \ \text{ each $k$ and for all } a_1,\ldots,a_n\geq0. 
$$
Taking a single $a_j$ to be nonzero, you get $\Phi_{kj}\geq0$ for all $k,j$. The converse is trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your precious help Martin! So is it sufficient to assume that the map is unital to say that it is stochastic. I don't know much about markov chains yet.. and what about positivity? I guess that is because we're talking about transitions probabilities so each entry must be between 0 and 1 and hence positive.. but I still tend to confuse the positivity of the map and the positivity of the matrix(does this mean that the entries are all greater than 0 in this setup?)

Comment: Positivity in your setting is entrywise; I've added that into the answer.

Comment: I can't thank you enough.^^ The cone of positive elements of $\mathbb{C}^N$ are the elements that can be written as $|\lambda|^2$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^N$ right?

Comment: Yes, they are precisely the $n$-tuples with all non-negative entries. One of several ways to notice it is that $$\mathbb C^n=\{f:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\mathbb C\}=C(\{1,\ldots,n\}).$$ Positivity in $C(X)$ is pointwise positivity.